# Is this solution to a problem concerning the equation $a^2=(m^yn^x)^z$ where $m=a^x$ and $n=a^y$correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

> If $m=a^x, n=a^y$ and $a^2=(m^yn^x)^z$

Show that $xyz = 1$

I have the above problem in my textbook (which does not provide an answer).

This is my attempt at a solution:

\begin{align*}
(a^xa^y)^z&=a^2\\
a^{x+y}&=a^2\\
(a^2)^z&=a^2 \Rightarrow z=1, xyz=1 \cdot 1\cdot 1
\end{align*}

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Is there a typo in your title? It has two $m$'s and no $n$ in the equation containing $a^2$

Comment: I think that should be $n^x$ instead of $m^x$

Comment: Yes, apologies, fixed.

Comment: why is $a^{x+y}=a^2$? Shouldn't it be $(a^{x+y})^z=a^2$?

Comment: As hinted in ajotatxe's answer, unless more is known about the possible values of $a$, this is simply not true, with a trivial counterexample being $a=1$, $x=y=z=2$. Is this the complete problem in your textbook, or have you left out some information? It could be general information that your textbook provides for all problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not correct. Your first step in substituting $m$ and $n$ should give you $$a^2=(a^{xy}a^{xy})^z$$The right hand side is equivalent to $a^{2xyz}$. Therefore, $2=2xyz$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 12):

The expression for $a^2$ would be

$$a^2=((a^x)^y(a^y)^x)^z=(a^{2xy})^z=a^{2xyz}$$

And, **assuming that $a$ is positive and is not $1$**,
$$2=2xyz$$

Answer (score 4):

The correct approach is as follows:

$$m^y = a^{xy}$$
$$n^x = a^{xy}$$

Therefore,
$$a^2 = \left(m^y n^x\right)^z = \left(a^{xy} a^{xy}\right)^z = \left(a^{2xy}\right)^z = a^{2xyz}.$$

Consequently,
$$2 = 2xyz$$
which implies that
$$xyz = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the above answers that your solution needs a bit of a correction.

Alternately, You can also prove this as follows:

$m^y=a^{xy}$ and $n^x=a^{xy}$

Therefore, $a^2=(m^yn^x)z=(a^{xy}a^{xy})^z=(a^{2xy})^z=a^{2xyz}$

Now, $a^2=a^{2xy}$.

Taking Log to the base $a$ on both the sides, we get,

$2log_{a}a=(2xyz)log_{a}a$ $\Longrightarrow$$2xyz=2$$\Longrightarrow$$xyz=1$